# Can someone help me find the sum of the following series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, fractals

I am working on one of the fractals and finding its convergent area.

$$\begin{align}  
S & = 1+3\left(\frac{1}{9}+4(\frac{1}{9^2})+4^2(\frac{1}{9^3})+...\right)\\
& =  1+3*\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \left[\frac{4^i}{9^{i+1}}\right] 
\end{align}$$

I want to say that I am looking at a geometric series, but I'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It *is* a geometric series. Pull out a factor $\frac19$ from the sum and you should see that the general term under the sum is $\frac{4^i}{9^i}$.

Comment: Thank you ! I guess I was too tired to see that.